# ValueError: I/O operation on closed file when making animation

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, ffmpeg

I am using matplotlib and ffmpeg to do some animations. I usually code on a remote server because the code runs faster; we are having some issues making animations on the remote server. Here is an example of code that works perfectly on my local mac but does not work remotely.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('agg')
import matplotlib as mpl 
from matplotlib import animation
import pylab

def init():
    pylab.plot(pylab.arange(10), [0]*10)

def redraw(frame):
    pylab.plot(pylab.arange(10), pylab.arange(10) * frame)

fig = pylab.figure()
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, redraw, frames=10, interval=1000, init_func=init)
ani.save('animation.mp4')
```

I get the animation I want on my local machine (macOS Sierra). When I run it on the remote host (Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)), I get the following error message after 5 frames

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "animation.py", line 14, in <module>
    ani.save('animation.mp4')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 1200, in save
    writer.grab_frame(**savefig_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 35, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 241, in saving
    self.finish()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 367, in finish
    self.cleanup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 405, in cleanup
    out, err = self._proc.communicate()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/subprocess32.py", line 724, in communicate
    stdout, stderr = self._communicate(input, endtime, timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/subprocess32.py", line 1535, in _communicate
    orig_timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/subprocess32.py", line 1591, in _communicate_with_poll
    register_and_append(self.stdout, select_POLLIN_POLLPRI)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/subprocess32.py", line 1570, in register_and_append
    poller.register(file_obj.fileno(), eventmask)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

My local machine uses matplotlib version 2.0.0; the remote machine uses matplotlib version 2.2.2

On my local machine I have ffmpeg version 3.2.4

```
$ ffmpeg -version
ffmpeg version 3.2.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
built with Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)
configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.2.4 --enable-shared - 
-enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables 
--enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --disable-lzma --enable-vda
libavutil      55. 34.101 / 55. 34.101
libavcodec     57. 64.101 / 57. 64.101
libavformat    57. 56.101 / 57. 56.101
libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100
libavresample   3.  1.  0 /  3.  1.  0
libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
libpostproc    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100
```

On the remote host i have ffmpeg version 4.0.1

```
ffmpeg -version
ffmpeg version 4.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10+deb8u1)
configuration: --prefix=/usr/local
libavutil      56. 14.100 / 56. 14.100
libavcodec     58. 18.100 / 58. 18.100
libavformat    58. 12.100 / 58. 12.100
libavdevice    58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
libavfilter     7. 16.100 /  7. 16.100
libswscale      5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
libswresample   3.  1.100 /  3.  1.100
```

If I recall correctly I installed ffmpeg locally through homebrew; I have the anaconda distribution of python. On the remote machine we have the default version of python that comes with Jessie; I'm not sure how the sysadmin installed ffmpeg.

I am by no means an expert on ffmpeg, but I have generally never had issues with making animations in matplotlib on my local machine and I would really like to be able to make videos more quickly on the remote machine. Any help would be appreciated!

**Edit**
On the remote machine, the animation works if I use avconv as the writer instead of ffmpeg. I installed avconv locally...which led me to get the same ffmpeg issues locally (probably due to updating shared dependencies). However, I uninstalled ffmpeg and reinstalled it with x264 codec enables [Animations in ipython (jupyter) notebook - ValueError: I/O operation on closed file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42133545/animations-in-ipython-jupyter-notebook-valueerror-i-o-operation-on-closed-f)

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem on any of my remote machines so I don't think the code executed being remote is an issue (matplotlib 2.2.2, ffmpeg 3.4.2). It's not something silly such as that you are running out of disk space?

Comment: We keep all our largest files on a separate data drive, and I am having no trouble saving large pdfs (i.e. a scatterplot with 40000 points), so I don't think disk space is an issue

Comment: I suggest you update matplotlib and ffmpeg (although I don't think the latter is the issue, as it seems to me from the error message that you don't get that far).